# Trying to logging into a website using Curl

Tags: php, http, authentication, curl

I am new to curl and have tried many tutorials. Last attempt I made was using the following code:

```
<?php

  // INIT CURL

  $url="";

  function login($url)  {
    $result = "";
    $cookiePath = "/tmp/cookies.txt";
    // Initialize the page
    $page = curl_init();
    // Set some options
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.justanswer.com/login.aspx');
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

    $pattern = "#Set-Cookie: (.*?; path=.*?;.*?)\n#";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches);
    array_shift($matches);
    $cookie = implode("\n", $matches[0]);

    // Use the parsed cookies with the next request
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);

    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POST, false);

    // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Set the location of and send the cookies
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiePath);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiePath);

    // Send out POST data
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,                          "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__SSVIEWSTATE=18&__VIEWSTATE=&email=****&sign_in_type=returning&username=&password=****&remember=true&ctl00%24BodyContent%24btnLogin.x=99&ctl00%24BodyContent%24btnLogin.y=17&SC_SID=346833306&SC_GUID=d157264a-24e2-47c0-b545-259ea5298e19&JS_BOOL=true&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWAwL%2BraDpAgKUnpuXBgKp%2F%2BSDCG4uM7n2SYrFbuk10%2FLkC64jclbvH6dXKmxM06VHN92G");

    // Get the page
    return $page;

  }
  
  $page = login($url);

  // Go to the page and log in
  curl_exec($page);

  // Change the URL to the main page to check to see if the user is logged in
  curl_setopt($page, CURLOPT_URL, "");

  // Print the output
  print curl_exec($page);

?>
```

Please can somebody explain what I am doing wrong, I replicated the same POST request using LIVE HTTP headers extension on firefox and it was successful.

Login page is at http://www.justanswer.com/login.aspx

Please suggest

TIA

Comment: What exactly is the error you're having with the code?

Comment: Is there a still a problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the form variables as array, e.g:

```
$postVars = array("__EVENTTARGET"   => "",
                  "__EVENTARGUMENT" => "",
                  "__SSVIEWSTATE"   => "18",
                  "__VIEWSTATE"     => "",
                  "email"           => "****",
                  "sign_in_type"    => "returning"
                  "foo" => "bar");
```